# How do you hide this overflow?

Tags: html, css, layout, overflow

The following is an example of the layout I am trying to achieve. The only problem is, I want to hide the overflowing part of the blue box without screwing up the rest of the layout.  Any takers?
http://jsfiddle.net/seB5F/27/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this OK? http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/seB5F/33/

You have to remove `position:absolute`.
I'm using `display:inline-block` + `white-space:nowrap` instead of `float`.

Enhanced demo with `font-size:0` hack: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/seB5F/34/

Answer (score 0):

Youre CSS attribute for that div is 'absolute'. You probably want something like 'relative.

Comment: @vicTROLLA- nope- that would screw up the layout, you would have seen that if you tried it.

Comment: @Yarin That's kinda unfair, you haven't given us what you want it to look like, only what it looks like now (which is what you *don't* want it to look like). If you specify either `height=100%` or change `position:absolute` for the `parent` as well, it'd work. But you need to be clearer on what you want it to finally be.

Comment: You should be using `overflow: auto;`, not `position: absolute;` to handle those floats.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding - What's unclear?  I specifically explained I want to hide the overflow while retaining the current layout.  Don't understand your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

At your css

```
#stretchable-div{
    background:blue;
    position: absolute;
     width:200px;
}
```

Comment: That causes the `<div>` to just overflow down.

Comment: To not overflow down, he could include   height:100px; overflow:auto;

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer @vicTROLLA gave, you can use javascript to get the width of the red box, then set the width of the container for the blue boxes (stretchable-div, or whatever), and then set the overflow on that container to hidden.

So either you use `relative` to get it to act like it's inside that red box (may screw up positioning) or you use JS to set the correct styles on that blue container once the red has been rendered.  note, if you set the width on the container, it will automatically try to wrap the inner boxes below.  You'll probably want to use some calculation or hard-coded number to set the height, as well.

For example, making your CSS look like this:

```
#stretchable-div {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
   height: 60px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: absolute;
   width: 200px;
}
```

It looks like what it sounds like you want.  You would need to use either Javascript or a server-side language to calculate the correct widths/heights, unless you want to hard-code it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this http://jsfiddle.net/seB5F/32/